# How to find documents with specific field contains string using RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

So, I can make simple via url:

```
<elastic_host>/indexname/_search?pretty=true&q=text:*str*
```

I want to do the same with RestHighLevelClient, but it dosn't work:

```
 SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
    searchRequest.types(INDEX_TYPE);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(IMAGE_TEXT_FIELD_NAME, "*str*" );
    searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent query is not a match query but a `query_string` query, so you can replace the following line

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(IMAGE_TEXT_FIELD_NAME, "*str*" );
```

by this one

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*str*").field(IMAGE_TEXT_FIELD_NAME);
```